# Generate share URL Google Earth from Lat Long

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

How do I generate a sharable URL for Google Earth Web (https://earth.google.com/web/) when I only have the latitude and longitude?

e.g.
If I have the lat and lng for the centre of London:
`51.52864165,-0.1016182`, how do I convert that to the below link Google earth generates?

> https://earth.google.com/web/@51.52864165,-0.1016182,19.4719181a,57850.03959629d,35y,0h,0t,0r/data=CkkaRxJBCiUweDQ3ZDhhMDBiYWYyMWRlNzU6MHg1Mjk2M2E1YWRkZDUyYTk5GU-M0d_wwElAIYByJUxiWsC_KgZMb25kb24YAiAB

Thanks

Comment: https://earth.google.com/web/@51.52864165,-0.1016182 doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

In the URL, the firs two parameters after the @ symbol are latitude,longitude. So you could truncate that URL after the lat,lon parameters, like this:
https://earth.google.com/web/@51.52864165,-0.1016182

While that will start Earth at the desired location, the view will be pushed all the way down to the ground (looks bad).  So... you'll want to add a distance (range) parameter to indicate how far (in meters) from your lat/long you want the view to be.  For example:

https://earth.google.com/web/@51.52864165,-0.1016182,100000d